# Detailed dimensions of an aircraft engine compressor blade

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, dynamics, aircraft-design

I am working on rub-induced vibrations in compressor stages of aircraft engines. The work is carried out in partnership with a company, therefore there is a limited amount of it that could be published openly.

Is it feasible to release **[open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)** compressor or turbine blade designs (e.g., NACA airfoil profiles for wings), as is commonly done in the software industry? By which I mean, detailed dimensions—in particular for the cross-section profiles and stacking laws—and the associated material properties.

If this has already been done, I'm not aware of it. Are there specific obstacles preventing the open source movement from spreading from the programming world into the engineering world? If so, are they technical or non-technical obstacles and how could they be overcome?

Not only would these specific designs be very useful for my own work, displaying relevant characteristics and realistic behaviors from an engineering perspective, while sharing all geometry and material property details, would allow other researchers to reproduce published results.

Comment: This question was [discussed on Meta](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/135/) and has [an earlier incarnation on Aviation SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1614).

Answer (score 5):

The [ESA](http://www.spaceflight.esa.int/impress/text/education/Circular%20Motion/Turbine_Blades.html) has a page on compressor blades. They give a good dimensioned diagram of an approximate shape; here are some basic dimensions:

- **Length:** 300 mm
- **Width:** 30 mm
- **Height:** 70 mm
- **Thickness:** 5 mm

I can't find any *complete* open source designs (i.e. high-quality, technical engineering drawings), but this is a good approximation.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This gives indeed a good idea of the global dimensions of a turbine blade but, since its a fairly recent engine (RR Trent), there is no information on the crossection profiles nor the stacking law used. I was hoping for something older but with more info regarding the actual blade profile.